# How would I calculate aperture efficiency for an antenna?

Tags: antenna, antenna-theory

How to calculate [aperture efficiency](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/3643/what-is-the-aperture-efficiency-of-an-antenna) for an antenna with the following parameters:

- Big reflector diameter= 24 mm
- Gain= 9.265 dbi
- Frequency= 11.60 GHz

Comment: 24mm? Did you mean cm?

Answer (score 1):

For any antenna, also for wire antennas, you can calculate so called effective area with $A_{eff} = \frac{\lambda^2}{(4\pi)}G$. An ideal antenna with surface area of $A_{eff}$ absorbs the same amount of power from the plane wave as that antenna.
Aperture efficiency is defined as ratio of effective and physical surface area $\eta_{ap} = A_{eff}/A_{phys}$. For a circular reflector antenna the physical size is the area of your antenna facing the incoming plane wave $ A_{phys} = \pi(d/2)^2$.

Comment: Hi,Thank you, but what about Aphys(how I can calculate Aphys if I have the big reflector Diameter =24mm)

Comment: I have edited my answer

Comment: Are you sure about the input values? On a closer look it seems that your antenna diameter is barely a wavelength, not exactly a "big reflector"

Comment: Antennas diameter is 26 mm,antennas  height is 13.128 mm, gain is 9,265 dBi and frequency is 11.6 GHz.

Comment: @KawaAbdoula to repeat what the others have said: a reflector that's not even one wavelength is not a "big reflector". It doesn't actually work well as reflector, at all.